# Image gradient overly

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gradient

I have seen News Republic android app. it is really awesome application. as per my view, the developer team have applied unique gradient overlay in their application and that gives nice image output.
 here is a screenshot for the imageView before image got loaded:
     [image]

and this after:
[image]

is there any idea on how to get the same?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a drawable resource with a gradient. Then in your XML, add a `View` over top of the `ImageView` with the drawable resource set as the `View` background. Your drawable resource would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF000000"
        android:centerColor="#88000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: i have tried that but didn't get the same effect as in the news republic app. i guess the developer used two gradients applied on top and bottom of the image view. unfortunately iam not able to achieve the same.

Comment: Did you try setting the start color and end color to something opaque and the center color to transparent? A less efficient solution would be tojust make two different views (one at top and one at bottom) with specified or weighted heights. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: Just what I needed :)